# Connect to SQL Server using Excel ADO VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to access SQL Server 11.0 from Excel VBA using ADO using Trusted Authentication. I get an error trying to connect:

> "Invalid Connection"

My Connection strings I've tried are:

```
oCn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SBLQADBREPL;Database=SESDBTrusted_Connection=Yes;"
oCn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=SBLQADBREPL;Initial Catalog=SESDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

Does anyone have any idea why this won't connect?

Comment: Is that all of the code?

Comment: Also that first string is missing an `;` between you database and trusted connection, could be your reason why it's failing unless just a typo here

Comment: Try `Provider=SQLNCLI11`